# Error in Connecting my Android Studio Project to Firebase

Tags: android-studio

I want to connect my android studio to Firebase but i have this error:

> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2.
>   Show Details
>   Affected Modules: app

Also

> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3.
>   Show Details
>   Affected Modules: app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.socialnetwork"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Make sure your internet connection is stable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all i'd recommend you go to [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) for more clarity

Also in your android studio...you need to invalidate caches..To do that

Go to **File** > **Invalidate Caches\Restart** > **Invalidate**

Go to [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com) to add your project.

Download the **google-services.json** file and add it your directory

Then add `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'` in you build.gradle file

build.gradle:

```
  dependencies {
    // Add the following line:
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'  // Google Services plugin
  }
```

After that in your **app/build.gradle** file : It should look this way

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
   //FireBase
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'
}
//add this line
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Then **Sync** your project